# Красивая загрузка сайта

Tags: html, jquery, css3, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

написал сайт, хочу сделать чтобы он загружался как-нибудь красиво.
что-то типо загрузки с 0 до 100 процентов и потом медленное отображение сайта или же просто по очереди медленное появление блоков div

Comment: Хотите подложить свинью заказчику? Я всеми силами стараюсь избегать сайтов и программ, где что-либо происходит мееееееедленно и "красиво".

Comment: это тестовый проект)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

То, что Вы хотите, называется *preloader* и готовых решений куча. Ищите по фразе [«jquery preloader»](https://yandex.ru/search/?text=jquery%20preloader&clid=2236994&banerid=0489000000&win=200&lr=13).